# HTML table onDrop event

Tags: javascript, html

I have an HTML Table that I have both a mouse down event and a mouse up events and drag and drop rows works well. My only problem is that I can't figure out how to identify when the drop has completed. I need to loop the table rows and resort their row id's to save the sort order to a database.  If I call it using the mouse up then the drop has not occurred.  I've seen where a div can have a dropend or onDrop event but not a table.  Is this possible?

Comment: Atleast try your logic, and post what you tried.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to dig some more and came up with something that works

```
        $(function () {
        $("#citationAreaTopTable tbody").sortable({               
            appendTo: "parent",
            helper: getHelper, // "clone",
            stop: function (event, ui) {

                var attr = $(ui.item).attr('id');
                var tableName = $(this).parent().attr("id");

                $('#' + tableName + ' tr').each(function (event, ui) {
                    $(this).css('backgroundColor', 'white');
                });


                if (tableName == "citationAreaTopTable") {
                    var table = document.getElementById('citationAreaTopTable');
                    var pmidsText = '';
                    for (var i = 1; i < table.rows.length; i++) {
                        if (table.rows[i].cells.length) {
                            var id = (table.rows[i].id.substring(table.rows[i].id.indexOf("-") + 1));
                            pmidsText += id + ','
                        }
                    }
                    pmidsText = pmidsText.slice(0, -1);
                    $('#citationAreaTopList').html('<b>Selected PMIDS: </b>' + pmidsText);
                }
            },
            update: function (event, ui) {

                var tableName = $(this).parent().attr("id");
                var id = '';
                var index = 0;

                if (tableName === '"citationAreaTopTable") ') {
                  //do something
                }

                $('#' + tableName + ' tr').each(function (e, u) {
                    $(this).css('backgroundColor', 'white');
                    if (u.id) {
                        if (u.id.slice(index).length > 0) {
                            id += u.id.slice(index) + ',';
                        }
                    }

                });

                Save_Sort(id);
            }
        }).disableSelection();
```

This allows me to loop the table and pull out the row id's